# Перезагрузка .html и .css файлов gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

Мне нужно прослушивать файлы .scss и .html и перезагружать из при изменении

*gulpfile.js:*

```
var 
   gulp = require('gulp'),
   livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
   sass = require('gulp-sass'),
   autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
   cleancss = require('gulp-cleancss'),
   rename = require('gulp-rename');
gulp.task('reload-css', function () {
   gulp.src('./src/sass/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer({
         overrideBrowserslist: ['last 3 versions'],
         cascade: false
      }))
      .pipe(cleancss({compatibility: 'ie8'}))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css/'))
      .pipe(livereload())
});
gulp.task('reload-html', function () {
   gulp.src('./src/*.html')
      .pipe(livereload())
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
   livereload.listen();
   gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', gulp.parallel('reload-css', 'default'));
   gulp.watch('./src/*.html', gulp.parallel('reload-html', 'default'));
});
```

Когда, допустим, я сохраняю .scss файл, то все хорошо, но если я сохраню изменения в .html файле, то происходит это

```
[18:08:49] Starting 'reload-html'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'default'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'reload-html'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'default'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'reload-html'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'default'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'reload-html'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'default'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'reload-html'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'default'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'reload-html'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'default'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'reload-html'...
[18:08:49] Starting 'default'...
[18:08:49] D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\src\index.html reloaded.
[18:08:49] D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\src\index.html reloaded.
[18:08:49] D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\src\index.html reloaded.
[18:08:49] D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\src\index.html reloaded.
[18:08:49] D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\src\index.html reloaded.
[18:08:49] D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\src\index.html reloaded.
[18:08:49] D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\src\index.html reloaded.
```

**Как убрать эту многоразовую перезагрузку, при этом оставив функцию следить за 2 файлами сразу?**

Comment: Обычно такое поведение обусловлено ошибк[ой/ами] в коде, галп не может собрать код и постоянно его перезагружает. Поищите ошибки в коде и постоянная перезагрузка просто пропадет и все будет работать в штатном режиме. А еще лучше перейти на вебпак и не мучиться с галпом, я лично на нем собаку съел.

Answer (score 3):

Каждый раз, когда ваши файлы подвергаются изменению вы снова вызываете задачу `default`. Причем выполнение этой задачи вы осуществляете [параллельно](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/parallel/), а не [последовательно](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series/). И проблема даже не в параллельности или последовательности, а в том, что после запуска задачи `default` вы рекурсивно запускаете её снова и снова, после каждого изменения файла.

```js
gulp.task('default', () => {
  gulp.watch(..., gulp.parallel(..., 'default')); // Рекурсивный вызов задачи default
  gulp.watch(..., gulp.parallel(..., 'default')); // Рекурсивный вызов задачи default
});
```

Попробуйте заменить на этот код:

```js
gulp.task('default', function () {
   livereload.listen();
   gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', gulp.series('reload-css'));
   gulp.watch('./src/*.html', gulp.series('reload-html'));
});
```

или так, согласно [примеру](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-livereload):

```js
gulp.task('default', function () {
   livereload.listen();
   gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', ['reload-css']);
   gulp.watch('./src/*.html', ['reload-html']);
});
```

Итак по порядку разберемся как работает наблюдатель `watch`.
Если попытаться кратко объяснить суть работы наблюдателя - он следит за изменением файлов и структуры каталогов, далее пытается делегировать выполнение кода другим задачам переданным в качестве след. аргументов.

Если подробней рассмотреть [пример](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch/) из [официальной документации](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts), можно заметить что сигнатура метода `watch` принимает три параметра, первый из них является обязательным, остальные два не обязательны.

```js
gulp.watch(globs, [options], [task]);
```

Немного ниже описаны параметры наблюдателя:

- [globs](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts#globs) - это маска, по которому будет отслеживаться изменение структуры файловой системы (пути и файлы). Этот аргумент может быть представлен в качестве строки или массива. Если вы указали массив, тогда наблюдатель будет следить по нескольким правилам. Например за несколькими структурами каталогов `['src/html/*.html', 'src/pug/*.pug']`
- [options](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch#options) - Необязательный параметр, предоставляется в качестве объекта. Если вам нужно задать какие-то специфические правила отслеживания, вы можете задать свои правила в этом параметре. Там их много, подробней смотрите в документации.
- [task](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task) - здесь вызываются другие задачи из вашего gulp-файла. Предоставляется либо строкой либо массивом. Если вы указали массив, соответственно после изменений будут выполнятся несколько задач.

Примеры:

```js
// после изменения изображения выполняем задачу task1
gulp.watch('src/img/**', 'task1');

// если изображения были удалены, выполнить задачу task2
gulp.watch('src/img/**/*', { events: 'unlink' }, ['task2']);

// после изменения изображений выполняем задачу task3
gulp.watch(['src/img/*.png','src/img/*.jpg'], 'task3');

// после изменения html-файлов выполняем несколько задач
gulp.watch('src/html/*.html', ['task4', 'task5']);
// тоже самое
gulp.watch('src/html/*.html', gulp.series('task4', 'task5'));

// тоже самое, но выполнить несколько задач одновременно (параллельно)
gulp.watch('src/html/*.html', gulp.parallel('task4', 'task5'));
```

Касательно этого блока:

```js
// Объявляем новую задачу "default"
gulp.task('default', function () {
   livereload.listen();
   gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', ['reload-css']);
   gulp.watch('./src/*.html', ['reload-html']);
});
```

Прежде всего, как сказано из [документации](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts#tasks): "каждая задача gulp - это асинхронная функция JavaScript, которая либо принимает обратный вызов при первой ошибке, либо возвращает поток, обещание, эмиттер событий, дочерний процесс или наблюдаемое. Из-за некоторых ограничений платформы синхронные задачи не поддерживаются."

Каждая задача в gulp-файле доступна из командной строки, а также доступна для текущего контекста выполнения `Gulp` интерфейсом.

Пример оформления gulp-файла версии 4 можно посмотреть [здесь](https://github.com/yukal/template-presenta/blob/dev/gulpfile.js)

Comment: Вот этот пример: gulp.task('default', function () { livereload.listen(); gulp.watch('./src/sass/*.scss', ['reload-css']); gulp.watch('./src/*.html', ['reload-html']); }); Alexander Yukal, не могли бы вы объяснить его более подробно.