# Как переделать синтаксис gulpfile.js гальп 3 под гальп 4?

Tags: gulp

```
синтксис гальпа 3.9 перешел на 4 не знаю как исправить чего не хватает?

assert.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: build
    at getFunction (C:\rarus-test-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\normalizeArgs.js:21:9)
    at map (C:\rarus-test-master\node_modules\arr-map\index.js:20:14)
    at normalizeArgs (C:\rarus-test-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\normalizeArgs.js:30:10)
    at Gulp.series (C:\rarus-test-master\node_modules\undertaker\lib\series.js:13:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\rarus-test-master\gulpfile.js:119:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
PS C:\rarus-test-master> 



const gulp = require('gulp');
const html = require('gulp-html');
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
const gulpAutoprefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const gulpSass = require('gulp-sass');
const gulpWatch = require('gulp-watch');
const gulpSourceMap = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const gulpStylelint = require('gulp-stylelint');
const image = require('gulp-image');
const historyFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

gulp.task('stylesheets', () => gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(gulpStylelint({
        failAfterError: false,
        reporters: [
            {
                formatter: 'string',
                console: true,
                fix: true,
            },
        ],
    }))
    .pipe(gulpSourceMap.init())
    .pipe(gulpSass({
        outputStyle: 'compressed',
    })).on('error', gulpSass.logError)
    .pipe(gulpAutoprefix({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
    }))
    .pipe(gulpSourceMap.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()));

gulp.task('stylesheetsProduction', () => gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(gulpStylelint({
        failAfterError: true,
        reporters: [
            {
                formatter: 'string',
                console: true,
                fix: true,
            },
        ],
    }))
    .pipe(gulpSass({
        outputStyle: 'compressed',
    })).on('error', gulpSass.logError)
    .pipe(gulpAutoprefix({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/')));

gulp.task('js', () => gulp.src('./src/js/main.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()));

gulp.task('jsProduction', () => {
    webpackConfig.watch = false;

    gulp.src('./src/js/main.js')
        .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
});

gulp.task('image', () => gulp.src('./src/images/*')
    .pipe(image())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev/images'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()));

gulp.task('imageProduction', () => gulp.src('./src/images/*')
    .pipe(image())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/images')));

gulp.task('html', () => gulp.src('./src/template/**/*.html')
    .pipe(html())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dev'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream()));

gulp.task('htmlProduction', () => gulp.src('./src/template/**/*.html')
    .pipe(html())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build')));

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulpWatch(['./src/scss/**/*.scss'], () => {
        gulp.start('stylesheets');
    });
    gulpWatch(['./src/images/**/*'], () => {
        gulp.start('image');
    });
    gulpWatch(['./src/template/**/*.html'], () => {
        gulp.start('html');
    });
});



gulp.task('server', gulp.series(function () {
    browser.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './dev',
            middleware: [
                historyFallback(),
            ],
        },
        open: true,
        port: 8080,
    });
}));



gulp.task('server', gulp.series('build', function () {
    browser.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './dev',
            middleware: [
                historyFallback(),
            ],
        },
        open: true,
        port: 8080,
    });
}));


gulp.task('development', [
    'stylesheets',
    'js',
    'image',
    'html',
    'watch',
    'server',
]);

gulp.task('production', [
    'stylesheetsProduction',
    'jsProduction',
    'imageProduction',
    'htmlProduction',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите ответы [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149269/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-html-%d0%b8-css-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-gulp/1169337#1169337) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166733/gulp-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80/1169236#1169236), в этих постах я постарался дать подробный ответ по использованию интерфейса `Gulp 4` и из-за чего могут возникнуть проблемы. В самом низу вы найдете пример 4-ой версии.